# Different results for scale3d+translate3d vs. scale+translate

Tags: css, transform, scale, translate, translate3d

I just stumbled upon a very strange behavior when working with `transform: translate3d()`.
As long as I use only the `translate3d()` property everything works exactly as `translate()`. But if I combine the this with `scale3d()` the behavior changes.

See the attached exmple to see whats happening.

Why are the results different? Anyone any idea?

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-top:10px;
  display:flex;
  width: 650px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-shadow: 0px -30px 0px black inset; 

}

.translate,
.translate3d,
.translatey {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 24pt;
}

.translate {
  will-change: transform, scale;
  transform: scale(0.75) translate(0px, -22.5px);
  background-color:lightcoral;  
}

.translate3d {
  transform: translate3d(0, -22.5px, 0) scale3d(0.75, 0.75, 0.75);
  background-color:lightblue;  
}

.translatey {
  transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-22.5px);
  background-color:springgreen;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="translate">
    translate
  </div>
  <div class="translate3d">
    translate3d
  </div>
  <div class="translatey">
    translatey
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are changing the order. The transforms order is **relevant**

Comment: thank you, now I feel dumb :D

Comment: Never mind, it has happened to me some times